# How find elements inside iframe - Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

I am use Selenium IDE for simulate an user interaction with the application. I am using New Relic and the application is wrapped inside an iframe. How can to find elements inside the iframe?

For example:

```html
<iframe allowfullscreen="" class="AAKXAC-wnd-ThirdPartyComponent" src="https://4b1a7ce2-7a5d-418d-a75e-05611871ae7c-1.g0.nr-ext.net/#eyJjc3MiOlsiaHR0cHM6Ly9kMXpvYmJoOGt5dHJ0di5jbG91ZGZyb250Lm5ldC9wbGF0Zm9ybS8zcmQtYXBwLTU5N2RhZDBkLmNzcyJdLCJqcyI6WyJodHRwczovL2Qxem9iYmg4a3l0cnR2LmNsb3VkZnJvbnQubmV0L3BsYXRmb3JtLzNyZC1hcHAtYzRkZmIyNjguanMiXX0%3D">
  #document
  <html>
    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
</iframe>
```

When in Selenium IDE. I define a step:

```
verify element present   css=.mainContainer
```

Its returns me an error because the element with the class 'mainContainer' is inside in an iframe. How can find elements in iframe? I am use Selenium IDE in Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Select the newly inserted row as shown below:

[image]

While the newly `insert row` is `selected`, enter ‘`select frame`‘ command into the Command field and `index=0` (*which locates the first out of the available frames on the page*) as shown below:

Note: We have to increase the `index` value *say 1,2,3,4 etc*.  if the required frame is not identified.

[image]

Click on ‘Run current test’ option and observe that the test got executed and the ‘Hotels’ links inside the frame got clicked as shown below:

[image]